# Animated height change in Windows metro

Tags: xaml, animation, windows-8, windows-8.1

that will work as expander. I want to make expanding animated.
So, i made this:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SuspendExpand">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Suspend"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Expand">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="439" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="MyRectangle" EnableDependentAnimation="true"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Rectangle x:Name="MyRectangle" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="177" Margin="313,281,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="342" Tapped="rectangle_Tapped"/>
```

And method:

```
    private void rectangle_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Expand", true);
    }
```

But the expanding isn't animated.

But when i use this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="NewStory">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyRectangle"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="177"  EnableDependentAnimation="true" To="500" Duration="0:0:1" />
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
```

And method:

```
    private void rectangle_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NewStory.Begin();
    }
```

**It is animated. What is the difference? Does it mean that i can't use visual states?**

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because you're animating the Height property. If you animated using the scale transform it will work.

Like this:

```
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SuspendExpand">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Suspend" />
            <VisualState x:Name="Expand">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="2.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="MyRectangle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: No, this will scale the contents of the rectangle! In other words, if it will be Stack panel with items in it, items will be scaled acordingly. I have written a solution that works in my question, but i want to know why isn't it working in VisualStates